# Materialized View Snowflake - Need to enforce the client to always provide some condition

Tags: performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, materialized-views

I have created a materialized view in snowflake for my client. This materialized view itself contains huge data. So is there any way so that I will enforce my client to pass the date condition while performing any query(i.e where eventDate = xxx or eventDate in between x and y) to increase the further performance of querying??

**Note:-** My view has a column name as eventDate

Comment: you can create another materialized views based on eventDate

Answer (score 0):

No you can't enforce that someone uses a date condition in a SQL statement - assuming they are just using a SQL editor.

If you wanted to enforce this you would have to put some sort of wrapper round the SQL and force the user to interact with the wrapper rather than directly querying the table. For example, you could write a stored procedure that took the date in as a parameter and put in a default value, or threw an error, if the date parameter was null